# TFS2012 Build All projects in folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there a way that I can make a build definition for TFS2012 that will include all projects in a given folder ($\AllProjects for example)?  I would like such a feature so that each time a new project was added anywhere in the child folders I don't have to manually update the build definition.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible, but you can create one solution just for this purpose (something like DeployProjects.sln), with all projects that you want to build. For each new project, you will add it to this solution.

Comment: That's what I usually do, but I was hoping that I could avoid the extra maintenance if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind customizing the workflow you can do this.

Use the FindMatchingFiles activity to find all csproj files, then loop through them and use the MSBuild activity to build each one.

Although, I would stick with Rafael's advice and just create a sln specifically for TFS Build that contains all projects you want to build.

Comment: That's not a bad idea either, but of course build order is an important thing.  I actually have a small tool I wrote find + resolve order + build all projects that match a filter.  They want us to use a build server at work now (for quality) but I think I'll stick with something that works.